# MapFragment layout_height can't find solution

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, mapfragment

I have a problem with my layout that contains 2 fragments: "map" -top fragment and "fragmentLayout with details" - bottom one.
I want my map fragment to margin from top to second layout on the bottom, but i can't find the proper solution. My bottom Layout lakes all the screen space, and I can't see the map at all.

Here is my layout file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/map"
              android:layout_height="0dp"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_weight="1"
              android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>

    <fragment class="com.softserve.youRun.Fragment.WorkoutDetailsFragment"
              android:id="@+id/workout_details"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Workout details fragment layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/row_gradient">


    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView0"
            android:textColor="#002F2F"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:text="Date"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textDateDetails"
            android:textColor="#002F2F"
            android:text="00.00.00"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:textColor="#002F2F"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:text="Distance(m)"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/textView0"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textDistanceDetails"
            android:textColor="#002F2F"
            android:text="00.00"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/textDateDetails"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:textColor="#002F2F"
            android:text="Duration"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/textView1"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textDurationDetails"
            android:textColor="#002F2F"
            android:text="00:00:00"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/textDistanceDetails"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:textColor="#002F2F"
            android:text="Calories"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/textView2"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textCaloriesDetails"
            android:textColor="#002F2F"
            android:text="000"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/textDurationDetails"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            />

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:textColor="#002F2F"
            android:text="Coordinates"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/textView3"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textCoordinatesDetails"
            android:textColor="#002F2F"
            android:text="0"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/textCaloriesDetails"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your layout file should look like this. The screen is divided equally amongst the two fragments:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:orientation="vertical">

<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:layout_height="0dp"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>

<fragment class="com.softserve.youRun.Fragment.WorkoutDetailsFragment"
          android:id="@+id/workout_details"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="0dp"//added this line
          android:layout_weight="1"/> // and this too

</LinearLayout>
```